# .NET Regex number of overlaping matches

Tags: .net, regex

I have this RegEx that finds any permutation with one A, one B and two C's

```
 (?:(?<A>A)|(?<B>B)|(?<C>C)){4}(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>){2}
```

for example for this combination we have 3 matches (positions 1, 7, 15)

```
 ABCCABCABCABCAABCC
```

We need to know how many overlaping matches we have. In this case when we find a match in the first 4 positions, it starts looking for another match in the position 5.

We need it to start looking for the next match in the position 2, so the matches would be in the positions: 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 15

We'd have 7 matches in this example

```
 1. ABCC
 2. BCCA
 3. CCAB
 4. CABC
 7. CABC
 10. CABC
 15. ABCC
```

How can it be possible using RegEx to start looking for the next match in the next position instead in the next position after the complete secuence?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [**capturing group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) inside the [**look-ahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/lookahead-assertions-in-regular-expressions.html):

> Lookahead assertions do not consume any characters in the string. As a result, you can use them to find overlapping character sequences.

```
(?=(?<value>(?:(?<A>A)|(?<B>B)|(?<C>C)){4}(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>){2}))
   ^                                                               ^
```

> If you want to store the match of the regex inside a lookahead, you have to put capturing parentheses around the regex inside the lookahead, like this: `(?=(regex))`.

More [details on overlapping matches using regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#overlapping) can be found at Rexegg.com.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3d(%3f%3cvalue%3e(%3f%3a(%3f%3cA%3eA)%7c(%3f%3cB%3eB)%7c(%3f%3cC%3eC))%7b4%7d(%3f%3c-A%3e)(%3f%3c-B%3e)(%3f%3c-C%3e)%7b2%7d))&i=ABCCABCABCABCAABCC)

[image]

Comment: I hope this will work for you. Please feel free to drop a comment if you have any doubts.

Comment: Perfect, I was going to post the solution since I realized a few minutes ago. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If you want a generic way to find overlapping matches for any regex, just do the looping logic yourself:

```
var re = new Regex(@"(?:(?<A>A)|(?<B>B)|(?<C>C)){4}(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>){2}");
var input = "ABCCABCABCABCAABCC";

var m = re.Match(input);
while (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);

    // End of string reached
    if (m.Index == input.Length)
        break;

    // Match from the next index
    m = re.Match(input, m.Index + 1);
}
```

You could even extract this to an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Match> OverlappingMatches(this Regex regex, string input)
{
    var match = regex.Match(input);

    while (match.Success)
    {
        yield return match;

        if (match.Index == input.Length)
            break;

        match = regex.Match(input, match.Index + 1);
    }
}
```