# .NET Regex overlaping matches taking last character

Tags: .net, regex

I have this RegEx that finds any permutation with one A, one B and two C's

```
(?:(?<A>A)|(?<B>B)|(?<C>C)){4}(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>){2}
```

for example for this combination we have 3 matches (positions 1, 7, 15)

```
ABCCABCABCABCAABCC
```

If I add a lookahead assertion I can count the number of coincidences starting on the next position rather than the next position after the complete sequence

```
(?=(?<value>(?:(?<A>A)|(?<B>B)|(?<C>C)){4}(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>){2}))
   ^                                                               ^
```

And we'd have 7 matches in this example

```
1. ABCC
2. BCCA
3. CCAB
4. CABC
7. CABC
10. CABC
15. ABCC
```

As stribizhev helped in this previous post:
[.NET Regex number of overlaping matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509705/net-regex-number-of-overlaping-matches)

Now I need to find a sequence of all the possible combinations of, for example, ABC, but 3 times and overlapping one character.

For example, for the following sequence:

```
AABCBACBCCAACCB
```

This would have the sequence in position 1

```
Pos 1. ABC
Pos 3. CBA
Pos 5. ACB
```

So it looks a sequence where we have any combination of ABC that appears 3 times in a row, but taking as the first character the last one of the previous match.

I hope I explained well..

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need to do this with a regex? Even if it's possible, I suspect that iterating through the string and counting the relevant characters would be quicker and cleaner.

Comment: @sln Looks like OP use zero based `Pos` for last example.

Comment: @PetSerAl  - right you are, I'm going blind.

Comment: What if there are just 2 "almost consecutive" occurrences? What is the language you are writing that in? C#? Just regex won't help. Do you need the position details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with simple modification to [@stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev) solution.

First, you have only `C` not two:

```
(?:(?<A>A)|(?<B>B)|(?<C>C)){3}(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>)
```

As you want to start new match from last character, you can use lookahead assertion and capture only two character after it:

```
(?=(?:(?<A>A)|(?<B>B)|(?<C>C)){3}(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>))..
```

Now you just repeat that three times and capture just one last character:

```
(?:(?=(?:(?<A>A)|(?<B>B)|(?<C>C)){3}(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>))..){3}.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think we are getting close. I have edit my question since I think I didn't explain well.

Comment: I imagine it'd be something similar when you have 4 characters in the pattern (like ABCC) or 4 repetitions instead of three, but I can't figure out the formula...

Comment: @MikeJohnson Assuming you have `REGEX`, which match four character and you want four repetition: `(?:(?=REGEX).{3}){4}.`. First `{?}` would be number of character minus one, second `{?}` would be number of repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve that in C# - note that `s` variable will be modified during the whole process, so clone it before or use a copy:

```
var s = "AABCBACBCCAACCB AABCBACBCCAACCB AABBBAABCCAACCB";
var rx = new Regex("(?=(?<value>(?:(?<A>A)|(?<B>B)|(?<C>C)){3}(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>)))");
var m = rx.Match(s);
while (m.Success)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    list.Add(m.Groups["value"].Value);
    s = s.Substring(m.Groups["value"].Index+m.Groups["value"].Length-1);
    m = rx.Match(s);
    if (m.Success && m.Groups["value"].Index == 0)
    {
        list.Add(m.Groups["value"].Value);
        s = s.Substring(m.Groups["value"].Index+m.Groups["value"].Length-1);
        m = rx.Match(s);
        if (m.Success && m.Groups["value"].Index == 0)
        {
            list.Add(m.Groups["value"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
            s = s.Sustring(m.Groups["value"].Index+m.Groups["value"].Length-1);
            m = rx.Match(s);
        }
    }
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/0hvVfA)